# How can I get findOne to return one element?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a query like this:

```
customers.findOne({name:'X','files.author':'c','files.name':'d'},{'files.$':1},function(err,data2){...
```

My data is like this:

```
{
    name:"X"
    files:[
       {name:"b"
        author:"a"}
       {name:"d"
       author:"c"}
    ]
}
```

Apparently, if I do

This returns `files[0]`. I want `files[1]`.  How can I do this? Should this code already do this, and therefore, my error is elsewhere?

### Edit:

Apparently,
If I do `{name:'X','files.name':'d','files.author':'c'}`  it'll work.

If I do `{name:'X','files.author':'c','files.name':'d'}` it won't.

I also got my schema reversed. I made an edit to reflect this. `name` is defined above `author`, actually. So I have to query things in the order according to the schema when using Mongoose's `findOne`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to match multiple fields in the *same* array element, you need to use [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) instead of listing them separately:

```
customers.findOne(
    {name: 'X', files: {$elemMatch: {author: 'c', name: 'd'}}},
    {'files.$':1},
    function(err, data2) {...
```

When listed separately as you currently have it, they can each match different `files` array elements.

Comment: I enforce `files.name` as  unique, so while `author` can match many, `name` can only match one. With this in mind, could it still match different `files` array elements?

Comment: @Houseman Sure.  Without using `$elemMatch`, the query would match docs where there isn't a single `files` element that matched both `author` and `name`, but there's one element that matched `author` and another that matched `name`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `find` instead. It returns cursor so you can use `skip` and `limit` methods on it:

```
customers.find({...}).skip(1).limit(1);
```

Comment: Is this a mongoose thing or a mongodb thing? Can you link to the documentation?

Comment: It's mongo, all the drivers support it: [skip](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/) and [limit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I needed to flip my query and search for things in the order that they are defined in the schema.